# TFLite: Micro mutable Op Resolver does not name a type

Tags: tensorflow, arduino, arduino-nano

I am trying to compile a TFLite micro-based Arduino sketch using MicroMutableOpsResolver class (to only include required operations for reducing the memory usage).

Though see similar usage in TF lite example here - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/micro_speech/micro_speech_test.cc

But keep hitting the below compilation error.

```
IMU_Classifier_TinyML:22:1: error: 'micro_op_resolver' does not name a type
 micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
IMU_Classifier_TinyML:23:1: error: 'micro_op_resolver' does not name a type
 micro_op_resolver.AddSoftmax();
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
IMU_Classifier_TinyML:24:1: error: 'micro_op_resolver' does not name a type
 micro_op_resolver.AddRelu();
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Using library Arduino_LSM9DS1 at version 1.1.0 in folder: /home/balaji/Arduino/libraries/Arduino_LSM9DS1 
Using library Wire in folder: /home/balaji/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/mbed/1.3.2/libraries/Wire (legacy)
Using library Arduino_TensorFlowLite at version 2.4.0-ALPHA in folder: /home/balaji/Arduino/libraries/Arduino_TensorFlowLite 
exit status 1
'micro_op_resolver' does not name a type
```

The code snippet looks as below:

```
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>
#include <TensorFlowLite.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/micro_ops.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/version.h>

// Include the TFlite converted model header file
#include "model.h"

const float accelThreshold = 2.5;
const int numOfSamples = 119; // acceleration sample-rate

int samplesRead = numOfSamples;

tflite::MicroErrorReporter tfLiteErrorReporter;

/*Import only the required ops to reduce the memory usage*/
static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<3> micro_op_resolver;
micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();
micro_op_resolver.AddSoftmax();
micro_op_resolver.AddRelu();
```

Am I missing any dependency or could this be due to TF lite version mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the function calls like `micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();` must be placed into a function body. Something like this should compile:

```cpp
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>
#include <TensorFlowLite.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/micro_ops.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/version.h>

// Include the TFlite converted model header file
#include "model.h"

const float accelThreshold = 2.5;
const int numOfSamples = 119; // acceleration sample-rate

int samplesRead = numOfSamples;

tflite::MicroErrorReporter tfLiteErrorReporter;

/*Import only the required ops to reduce the memory usage*/
static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<3> micro_op_resolver;

void setup() {
  micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();
  micro_op_resolver.AddSoftmax();
  micro_op_resolver.AddRelu();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: I do have a setup() function but sorry I didn't get how would that help here? This is more of declaring the ops to be used per my understanding.

Comment: Unlike e.g. Python you cannot have code like `micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();` (function calls) outside of functions In C/C++, only type/function/variable declarations and such.

Comment: @Balaji any luck?

Comment: Yes, it works after moving the addition of ops as part of setup().